# Rendering a textured 3D cube in R

Tags: textures, rendering

I am trying to render a 3D cube in the R programming language, and add a texture to each cube face.

So far I have this code that draws the cube:

```
library('rgl'); library('magrittr') 

cube <- function(x=0,y=0,z=0, bordered=TRUE, filled = TRUE, lwd=2, scale=1, fillcol = gray(.95),bordercol ='black', ...) 
{
     mycube <- cube3d()
     mycube$vb[4,] <- mycube$vb[4,]/scale*2 

     for (i in 1:length(x)) { 
        if (bordered) { 
            bcube <- mycube bcube$material$lwd <- lwd
            bcube$material$front <- 'line' bcube$material$back <- 'line' 
            bcube %>% translate3d(x[i], y[i], z[i]) %>% shade3d
        }
        if (filled) {
            fcube <- mycube fcube$vb[4,] <- fcube$vb[4,]*1.01 
            fcube$material$col <- fillcol
            fcube %>% translate3d(x[i], y[i], z[i]) %>% shade3d
        }
    }
}
```

But I need help adding a texture to each face. How can I do that?

Comment: Presumably you started by searching for R programming tutorials and working through a few? What have you tried so far, and where have you gotten stuck? R isn't used very frequently in game development, so you may find folks on the mathematics or data science SE sites are more knowledgeable about it.

Comment: Well i started by drawing the 3D cube, but i didn't find the codes to add texture to each face

Comment: Then you should probably show the code you have for drawing the cube for starters, so folks know they don't have to tell you how to do that part, and we can find ways to incorporate the texture into your existing method.

Comment: You probably noticed that code belongs in your question, not in comments. Use the edit button at the bottom of your question to ensure it's complete and well formatted.

Comment: I used the code: library('rgl'); library('magrittr')   cube <- function(x=0,y=0,z=0, bordered=TRUE, filled = TRUE, lwd=2, scale=1,
fillcol = gray(.95),bordercol ='black', ...) { mycube <- cube3d() mycube$vb[4,] <- mycube$vb[4,]/scale*2
for (i in 1:length(x)) { if (bordered) {
bcube <- mycube
bcube$material$lwd <- lwd
bcube$material$front <- 'line'
bcube$material$back <- 'line' bcube %>% translate3d(x[i], y[i], z[i]) %>% shade3d}
if (filled) {fcube <- mycube
fcube$vb[4,] <- fcube$vb[4,]*1.01 fcube$material$col <- fillcol
fcube %>% translate3d(x[i], y[i], z[i]) %>% shade3d}}}

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, however, thanks to the code you posted (which should be in the question, which you can edit, by the way), I found [documentation on rgl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/rgl.pdf). As fas as I can tell you need to specify a material, and texcoords when creating your cube3d. When creating the material you specify the texture you want to use.

Comment: I've edited your code into your question, making my best guess about how it should be formatted. Please **edit your question** to make corrections if I've botched the formatting or syntax anywhere. In future, please ensure your question has all relevant details in it, so strangers don't have to fix it.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help and excuse me that's my first time using this platform